# Solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$. I attempted by substituting$\ y-2=t$ but not able to find the solution. The options are

a.$(x+2)^4(1+\frac{2y}{x})=ke^{\frac{2y}{x}}$

b. $(x+2)^4(1+\frac{2(y-2)}{(x+2)})=ke^{\frac{2(y-2)}{x+2)}}$

c.$(x+2)^3(1+\frac{2(y-2)}{(x+2)})=ke^{\frac{2(y-2)}{x+2)}}$

d. None of the above.

Comment: Ain't the solution supposed to be in the form $y(x)=\dots$ instead?

Comment: _but it is in this manner in the book_

Comment: _the answer in the solution booklet is b_ but there is only the solution. No work done.

Comment: @MattAllegro I wouldn't say that's necessary because $dy/dx$ can be found through implicit differentiation.

Comment: @Dylan True, as answer by JJacquelin clarifies. Before such answer I was missing some context and...level of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method to find the solution on implicit form is shown below.
Moreover, the explicit solujtion is obtained thanks to the Lambert W function :

[image]